# Find matching strings from array with multiple params

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, ecmascript-6

Not sure how to implement such a search with params as values and different params count. Looks like I need `Regex` & `match`. But params are not hardcoded in my matching (possible URLs array) - they are dynamic, and param value can be 0, 100, 777 and etc.

For example, I have such an array of strings to match:

```
[
'urlA/someId1',
'urlA/someId1/someSubUrlA/someId2',
'urlB/someId1/someId2'
'urlB/someId1/someSubUrlB/someId2'
]
```

ps: I can edit this array, so for example surround params with `{}` etc.

and when I try to run a search for: `http://example.com/urlA/100/someSubUrlA/200`
it should return `urlA/someId1/someSubUrlA/someId2`

when I try to run a search for: `http://example.com/urlA/150`
it should return `urlA/someId1`

and from what I can see I can use `Regex` & `.match` with `.find()`. But I'm confused about how to write custom matcher with custom parameters & their count. Is it possible somehow in JS?

Comment: I guess you could use: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp It's also used in react router, for example.

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you mean by multiple params. I think you rather mean everything after a domain in a url. To find that, you would loop through the array and execute regex upon each item, returning perhaps another array of everything after the domain.

Comment: I think this question requires more clarity to be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want that given a url to find the abstract representation of it. Right?

```
let data = [
  'urlA/someId1',
  'urlA/someId1/someSubUrlA/someId2',
  'urlB/someId1/someId2',
  'urlB/someId1/someSubUrlB/someId2'
];

function finder(url) {
  let afterDomain = url.match(/http:\/\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]*\/(.*)/)[1];
  let matcher = afterDomain.replace(/\d+/g, "[^\/]+");
  return data.find(x => (new RegExp(matcher)).test(x))
}

finder("http://example.com/urlA/100/"); // "urlA/someId1"
finder("http://example.com/urlA/100/someSubUrlA/200"); // "urlA/someId1/someSubUrlA/someId2"
```